# Inequality involving radius of convergence of Taylor series

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

Let $(a_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset \mathbb{C}$ and $z \in \mathbb{C}$ . Let $f(z)=\sum\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} a_{n}z^n$ have radius of convergence $R_{0}$ and let $z_{0}$ be such that $|z_{0}| < R_{0}$.  Let $R_{1}$ be the radius of convergence of the Taylor series of $f$ around $z_{0}$. I want to prove that $R_{0}-z_{0} \leq R_{1} \leq R_{0}+z_{0}.$

I know that since $|z_{0}| < R_{0}$, there exists $r_{0}>0$ such that $|z_{0}| < r_{0}< R_{0}$ and so $f(z_{0})=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n}z_{0}^n$ converges uniformly on $\overline{B_{r_{0}}(0)}$.

I also know that if $r_1<R_{1}$ then $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(z_0)}{n!} (z-z_{0})^n$ converges to $f(z)$ on $\overline{B_{r_{1}}(z_0)}$. But I can't seem to put these things together in order to prove the inequality.

Comment: Do you know that the Taylor series of $f$ about $a$ converges (to $f$) in the largest disk $D_r(a)$ with centre $a$ such that $f$ is holomorphic on $D_r(a)$?

Comment: Yes, as a corollary of Taylor's Theorem. Guess I haven't used that.

Comment: So you need to look at the inclusions between $D_\rho(z_0)$ and $D_r(0)$ when a) $r = R_0$ and $\rho \leqslant R_0-\lvert z_0\rvert$, or b) $\rho > R_0 + \lvert z_0\rvert$ and $r > R_0$.